# Why is PHPmailer adding Embedded images as attachments?

Tags: phpmailer

PHPMailer version 6.18

I reviewed numerous examples of how to add an inline/embedded image with phpmailer. Following the examples the image gets added as an attachment versus inline. Have tried both text and html.

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
$attachment = "packages/ds/reservations/venmo-code.jpg";
$mail->Body = "
<style type='text/css'> img { max-width: 100%; width: 480px; } </style>
<h2>Including an embeded image</h2>
<img src='cid:venmo' ";

#$mail->addEmbeddedImage("$attachment", "venmo");
#$mail->addEmbeddedImage("$attachment", "venmo","base64","image/jpeg"); // fails
$mail->addEmbeddedImage("$attachment", "venmo","image/jpeg", "base64"); // reversed
```

Neither the commented #$mail or second option work, getting the same result. The following, reversing image/jpeg with base64 errors out so I reversed it as above just to see.What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Very silly mistake. I missed closing the html on the img src line:

Should be:

<img src='cid:venmo' />";